# Macbook Pro (mid 2009) crashes after RAM upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, crash, restart

I just upgraded the RAM memory from 2x2GB ram to 2x4GB on my Macbook Pro mid-2009. A few minutes after startup with the new memory the screen freezes for 2 seconds, then the Macbook restarts. When it turns back on, it says "Your computer restarted because of a problem. Press any key or wait a few seconds to continue starting up."

If I remove one of the two new memory sticks and only run with 1x4GB the Macbook runs without crashing or any problems. Why does it crash with 2x4GB memory?

The new memory is "Macmemory corsair ddr3 cmsa8gx3m2a1333c9".

I also get this crash report when starting up;

```
Tue Apr 14 09:13:02 2020
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff800b3cfdab): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800b6febe5, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00000001089d8000, CR3: 0x0000000075195000, CR4: 0x00000000000026e0
RAX: 0xffffff8027896a98, RBX: 0xffffff8027896a50, RCX: 0xffffff8027896a98, RDX: 0xffffff801cd39e08
RSP: 0xffffff8114b5b920, RBP: 0xffffff8114b5b960, RSI: 0x000000000004aede, RDI: 0xffffff801cd39e08
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0xffffff8114b5bca0, R10: 0x000000000920016b, R11: 0x0000000000000020
R12: 0xffbfff80278b35a0, R13: 0xffffff801cd39e08, R14: 0x000000000004aede, R15: 0xffffff801cd39808
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff800b6febe5, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x00000001089d8000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x1, PL: 1

Mac OS version: 15G22010

System model name: MacBookPro5,5 (Mac-F2268AC8)

Model: MacBookPro5,5, BootROM MBP55.00AC.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2,53 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.47f2

Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341384758334D324131333333433920

Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341384758334D324131333333433920
```

Comment: At very least, Apple suggests to use 1066 MHz modules with this model. It could be a reason of crash.

Comment: @nicael is correct (and should write this up as an answer)  You need PC3-8500 memory.  See [everymac.com](https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/8/system_profiler/)

Comment: Thank you, just ordered new memory PC3-8500 1066MHz!

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend to use compatible memory, at least.

As per [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP541?viewlocale=en_US), it is 1066 MHz memory

> **Processor and memory**
>    - ...
>   - 4GB (two 2GB SO-DIMMs) of 1066MHz DDR3 memory; two SO-DIMM slots support up to 8GB

Also, I used to have such a 13 Inch '09 Macbook, I'm pretty sure it was MacBook5,5, and it was equipped with 8GB of RAM and 500GB SSD; it worked just fine.